# SP2-0552: Bind variable "N3" not declared

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

This  is  a code for comparing three numbers and to print the greatest value.

```
declare
n1 number(2);
n2 number(2); 
n3 number(2); 
begin
n1:=&n1;
n2:=&n2:
n3:=&n3;
if n1>n2 and n1>n3 then
dbms_output.put_line('The greatest number is n1 '||n1);
else if n2>n1 and n2>n3 then
dbms_output.put_line('The greatest number is n2 '||n2);
else 
dbms_output.put_line('The greatest number is n3 '||n3);
end if;
end;
/
```

When i try to run this pl sql code in oracle it says

```
old   6: n1:=&n1;
new   6: n1:=4;
Enter value for n2: 5
old   7: n2:=&n2:
new   7: n2:=5:
Enter value for n3: 6
old   8: n3:=&n3;
new   8: n3:=6;
SP2-0552: Bind variable "N3" not declared.
```

**Can u tell me where it is wrong???I would be very grateful**

Comment: why don't you use the oracle `GREATEST` function? it fits quite well for your purpose

Comment: Ok,but can u tell me what is wrong in this???

Comment: Sure, the normal way to do what you are doing is creating an SP, not using anonymous blocks.

Comment: @JaimeDrq `GREATEST` tells you which is the largest value but not which variable is the largest. Also, stored procedures are inappropriate when it is a one-off calculation and you do not want/need to create a procedure in the database.

Comment: Hi @MT0, I don't understand well why `GREATEST` doesn't fit well to get the greatest number of 3, can you explain please?

Comment: @JaimeDrq The `GREATEST` function will tell you that the greatest value is `3` but it will not tell you that the variable that contains the greatest value is, for example, `N2`. The OP is finding both the greatest value and the identity of the variable that contains that greatest value.

Comment: Ah ok... thanks @MT0 I didn't see... you are right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 3 errors (typos):

- You need the `DECLARE` keyword before you start declaring variables.
- `n2:=&n2:` should be `n2:=&n2;`
- `else if` should be `elsif` (or, if you want to keep the `else if` then you need a second `end if;` to terminate that second `if` statement)

```sql
DECLARE
  n1 number(2);
  n2 number(2); 
  n3 number(2); 
begin
  n1:=&n1;
  n2:=&n2;
  n3:=&n3;
  if n1>n2 and n1>n3 then
    dbms_output.put_line('The greatest number is n1 '||n1);
  elsif n2>n1 and n2>n3 then
    dbms_output.put_line('The greatest number is n2 '||n2);
  else 
    dbms_output.put_line('The greatest number is n3 '||n3);
  end if;
end;
/
```